# Submit Form Issue in Search Bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

No matter what I try I cannot get this to submit my search form

```html
<div id="search_bar_container" style="z-index:99999">
  <div class="container">
    <form action="tour-list-search-results.php" method="post" name="search_2" id="search_2">
      <div class="search_bar">

        <div class="nav-searchfield-outer">
          <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="field-keywords" placeholder="Type your search terms ...." id="twotabsearchtextbox">
        </div>
        <div class="nav-submit-button">
          <input type="submit" onclick="this.form.submit();" name="button" id="button" class="nav-submit-input" value="Submit">
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- End search bar-->
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /search_bar-->
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you clearly explain your issue?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine, BUT your HTML looks invalid. The form is not nested correctly and you have an extra  tag.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you just need to tidy up your `HTML` and the form will submit when you click the button.

```js
$("form").submit(function( event ) {
   alert( "Form submitted" );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search_bar_container" style="z-index:99999">
    <div class="container">
        <form action="tour-list-search-results.php" method="post" name="search_2" id="search_2">
            <div class="search_bar">
                <div class="nav-searchfield-outer">
                    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="field-keywords" placeholder="Type your search terms ...." id="twotabsearchtextbox" />
                </div>
                <div class="nav-submit-button">
                    <input type="submit" onclick="this.form.submit();" name="button" id="button" class="nav-submit-input" value="Submit" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End search bar-->
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /search_bar-->
</div>
```

I have formatted your HTML correctly and as you can se, the form submits on click of the button.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kq84cq46/1/)